# Probability normal distribution question

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

I had this question on a quiz, since I don't have the solution for it I solved it. can anyone tell me if I did it right?

The weight of a coffee capsule is normally distributed with a mean of 13.6 grams and a standard deviation of 0.8 gram. Suppose that 25 coffee capsules are placed in a package. Also, suppose that the weights of coffee capsules are independent. What is the probability that the weight of a package of 25 coffee capsules is less than 335 grams?

25 coffees capsule

$Y=X_1+X_2+X_3+\dots+X_{25}$

$E(X)=13.6$

$E(Y)=13.6\cdot25$

$V(X)=0.8^2$

$V(Y)=(0.8^2)\cdot25=16$

standard deviation of $Y=4$

$P(X<335)=P\Big(Z\leq \frac{335-340}{4}\Big)=P(Z\leq -1.25)=0.1056$

Is this correct?

Just one more question, can we add standard deviations instead?
because the first time I attempted this problem  I multiplied standard deviation by 25. But I heard that its not a linear or something. Just want to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this correct?

Yes, absolutely.

> Just one more question, can we add standard deviations instead?

No, you cannot.